# Getting signal from high voltage side of PCB to low voltage side

Tags: pcb-design

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS799I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Rough PCB layout showing 2 HV sides of PCB and LV side separated by 8mm clearance]

I am designing a PCB that has both a high voltage side and a low voltage side.

They are separated by roughly 8mm.

There are I/O lines on the high side that, most of the time, input a very low voltage/low current signal connected to an op amp and then to an ADC in an MCU.

These same input lines are also used to output a high voltage signal for a very brief period. Obviously the low voltage side has to be protected from these high voltage output.

Typically I would use a couple resistors and zener diodes, but in this case, I still need to get a signal across to the low voltage side.

How is this done?

In case you're wondering, this is for an AED with a novel delivery mechanism that I've tested.

Low voltage is the ECG sense while High Voltage is the shock.

The PCB is for a somewhat production prototype.

edit:  simplified schematic (ignore component names) and simplified PCB layout added

Comment: Draw a diagram and please be clear about what signals you wish to transmit across the interface (signal levels and operating frequency and required accuracy).

Comment: Without a schematic, it's hard to tell exactly what you want, but in general terms hi-side/low-side communication is generally done either with optocouplers or transformers, with optocouplers being rather more common and easier to use for digital signals.

Answer (score 0):

Analog Devices and Burr-Brown (now a part of Texas Inst.) are big in isolation amplifiers.  Probably more expansive than home-brew, but you get tested, documented, and repeatable performance complete with safety certifications.